# let $a,b,c>0$ prove that $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle $\iff$ $a^4+b^4+c^4-2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)<0$ what is the geometric explanation?

Tags: geometry

> let $a,b,c>0$ prove that $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle $\iff$ $a^4+b^4+c^4-2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)<0$ what is the geometric explanation?

This is what I tried:

First just write the inequality in a different form using algebraic properties
$$-(a^4+b^4+c^4-2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2)>0$$ $$\iff$$
$$-(a^4+b^4+c^4-2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2-2c^2a^2-4b^2c^2)>0$$ $$\iff$$
$$-((a^2-b^2-c^2)^2-4b^2c^2)>0$$ $$\iff$$
$$-((a^2-b^2-c^2)^2-(2bc)^2)>0$$ $$\iff$$
$$-(a^2-b^2-c^2)^2+(2bc)^2>0$$ $$\iff$$
$$-(a^2-b^2-c^2+2bc)(a^2-b^2-c^2-2bc)>0$$ $$\iff$$
$$-(a^2-(b-c)^2)(a^2-(b+c)^2)>0$$ $$\iff$$
$$-(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(a+b+c)(a-b-c)>0$$ $$\iff$$
$$(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(a+b+c)(a-b-c)<0$$

this was my final result.. we know that in triangle
$$\begin{cases}
 a+b-c>0\\
a-b+c>0\\
-a+b+c>0
\end{cases} $$

and given that $a,b,c>0$

according to $(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(a+b+c)(a-b-c)<0$ we get that this multiplication is negative and according to what we needed to prove it is supposed to be negative

I do not know how to continue to prove this $iff$ statement or what is the geometric explanation.

appreciate any tips and help

Comment: You've done well! $a+b-c>0, a-b+c>0, a+b+c>0, a-b-c \color{red}{<} 0.$

Comment: @RDK Thank you! , but what is the geometric explanation of this? is it what i typed about the sides? or is there anything else?

Comment: In Plane Geometry, in any triangle, the sum of the lengths of any two of the sides of the triangle is greater than the length of the third side of the triangle.

Comment: @Adamrk this is a consequence of the triangle inequality. I think of it as meaning if I got from one place to another and stop somewhere else on the way I can't make my trip shorter. It can be on my way or out of my way but it's not a shortcut.

Comment: @Adamrk: $a^4+b^4+c^4-2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)<0$ is not true for equilateral triangles and zero area triangles where the vertices are in the same straight line. Right and obtuse triangles $(1,1,\sqrt 3)$ etc. may be investigated for maximum enclosed area.